# Create a DAG from file dependencies in Rust

Tags: rust

I'm trying to build a petgraph DAG from a sql file in Rust and am struggling with how to build the transitive dependencies.

Getting the first node's parents is simple enough:

```
use sqlparser::{dialect::SnowflakeDialect, parser::Parser, ast::visit_relations};
use core::ops::ControlFlow;

fn main() {

    let query = "select 1 from schema.tab1 join schema.tab2";
    let _qry_tab_2 = "select 1 from schema.tab4";

    let dialect = SnowflakeDialect {};
    let ast = Parser::parse_sql(&dialect, query).unwrap();

    let mut visited = vec![];
    visit_relations(&ast, |relation| {
        visited.push(format!("{relation}"));
        ControlFlow::<()>::Continue(())
    });

    assert_eq!("schema.tab1", visited[0])
}
```

But getting the next ones and so on I'm not really sure how to proceed. For example, the next iteration would be for `schema.tab1`'s dependencies and then the dependencies of those.

Ideally I'd like to have an output be something like:

```
{schema.tab1: [schema.tab2, schema.tab3],
 schema.tab2: [schema.tab4],
 schema.tab3: [schema.tab4],
 schema.tab4: []
}
```

which would make it simple to build a graph from the result like so:

```
           --(node1) 
          /
(node0) --
          \
           --(node2)--(node3)
```

What's the idiomatic way in Rust to traverse such a problem?

Comment: When you're asking an SO question, it's always a good idea to make sure whatever code you post can be compiled and run by others. I guess you're using `sqlparser::{dialect::SnowflakeDialect, parser::Parser};`, but where is `visit_relations` from? Also, it might be nice to make `tab1`-`4` appear in your example `query`. That would help me understand what's going on a bit more.

Comment: `visit_relations` is a feature of `sqlparser`. I've updated the question to address the comments.

Comment: Oooh, it seems that `sqlparser` just released 0.31 which hid that function behind the `visitor` feature. Hence my confusion.

Comment: Hm, what I still don't understand is where you get information like `schema.tab1: [schema.tab2, schema.tab3]` from. Is that somehow given? (If so, I don't understand what you need sql parsing for, you can just directly build a graph from that.) Or do you somewhere have a list that maps schemas to SQL queries like `"schema.tab1": "select 1 from schema.tab2 join schema.tab3"` or so?

Comment: My apologies for the confusion. It was simply an example data structure that I'd like to build so that I can build a graph from it. The specific issue I have is how to recursively (or otherwise) traverse a sql file's dependencies to build such a structure in the first place. I only have a directory of sql scripts, no mappings.

Comment: So, given this directory of SQL scripts files, where does the dependency come from? Normally, each query stands alone, doesn't it? Sure, each query depends on some relations to exist, but how do the relations depend on the queries?

Comment: The sql script itself has FROM/JOIN statements that correspond to tables which have the same names as the other sql files in the directory. I'd like to build a logical graph of those relations. Each node would be a dir path and each edge something like `Parent`

Comment: Ah, so it's in the filename. That might have been worth mentioning from the start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```rust
use anyhow::Context;
use sqlparser::{dialect::SnowflakeDialect, parser::Parser};

fn main() -> anyhow::Result<()> {
    stackoverflow_example_setup();

    let relationships = relationships()?;
    dbg!(&relationships);

    let graph = mk_graph(&relationships);
    let dot = petgraph::dot::Dot::with_config(&graph, &[petgraph::dot::Config::EdgeNoLabel]);
    println!("{:?}", dot);
    Ok(())
}

fn relationships() -> anyhow::Result<Vec<(String, Vec<String>)>> {
    let relationships = std::fs::read_dir("./sqlfiles")?
        .map(|entry| {
            let entry = entry.context("Read dir entry failure")?;
            let edges = relationships_from_dirent(&entry)
                .with_context(|| format!("Read {}", entry.path().to_string_lossy()))?;
            Ok(edges)
        })
        .collect::<anyhow::Result<_>>()?;
    Ok(relationships)
}

fn relationships_from_dirent(entry: &std::fs::DirEntry) -> anyhow::Result<(String, Vec<String>)> {
    let path = entry.path();
    let query = std::fs::read(&path).context("Can't read")?;
    let query = String::from_utf8(query).context("Invalid UTF-8")?;
    let ast = Parser::parse_sql(&(SnowflakeDialect {}), &query).context("Can't parse")?;
    let parent = path.file_name().context("no filename")?;
    let parent = parent.to_str().context("Non-UTF8 filename")?.to_owned();
    let mut children = vec![];
    sqlparser::ast::visit_relations(&ast, |relation| {
        children.push(format!("{relation}"));
        std::ops::ControlFlow::<()>::Continue(())
    });
    Ok((parent, children))
}

fn mk_graph<'a>(edges: &'a Vec<(String, Vec<String>)>) -> petgraph::Graph<&'a str, ()> {
    let mut graph = petgraph::Graph::<&str, ()>::new();
    let mut nodes = std::collections::HashMap::<&str, petgraph::graph::NodeIndex>::new();
    for (paren, children) in edges {
        let paren = *nodes.entry(paren).or_insert_with(|| graph.add_node(paren));
        for child in children {
            let child = *nodes.entry(child).or_insert_with(|| graph.add_node(child));
            graph.add_edge(paren, child, ());
        }
    }
    graph
}

fn stackoverflow_example_setup() {
    std::env::set_current_dir(env!("CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR")).unwrap();
    std::fs::remove_dir_all("./sqlfiles").ok();
    std::fs::create_dir("./sqlfiles").ok();
    std::fs::write(
        "./sqlfiles/schema.tab1",
        "select 1 from schema.tab2 JOIN schema.tab3",
    )
    .unwrap();
    std::fs::write("./sqlfiles/schema.tab2", "select 1 from schema.tab4").unwrap();
    std::fs::write("./sqlfiles/schema.tab3", "select 1 from schema.tab4").unwrap();
    std::fs::write("./sqlfiles/schema.tab4", "select 1").unwrap();
}
```

`relationships_from_dirent` reads one file, parses the sql in it, and returns a tuple `(parent_relationship, [child_relationship1, …])`. `mk_graph` throws that into `petgraph`.